# React Context API Global state does not update across different routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

When I increment the state from Page1,it gets upadated for Page1. But when I go to Page2 the state becomes 0 again.I don't get the upadated state from Page1. Is there any way to create a global state across routes?

context.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export const Context = React.createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ state, setstate }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Page1.js

```
 const Page1 = () => {
      const { state, setstate } = useContext(Context);
      console.log("Page1: ", state);
       return (
        <div>
          <h1>PAGE 1</h1>
          {state}
          <button onClick={() => setstate(state + 1)}>INC</button>
        </div>
       );
     };
```

Page2.js

```
const Page2 = () => {
  const { state, setstate } = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PAGE 2</h1>
      {state}

      <button onClick={() => setstate(state + 1)}>INC</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your App with ContextProvider?

Comment: Just to be clear, how are you navigating between routes? Do you have a client-side router like Reach Router or React Router? Or are you clicking <a> links or manually typing the page address in? If you are clicking <a> elements or manually typing the page address in then you are unmounting and remounting everything, i.e., your page is starting from scratch, resetting the state.

Comment: I have wrapped my whole app with Contextprovider

Comment: Yes I am navigating manually as well as by Link from react-router.

Comment: How would I navigate without resetting the whole page?